# https ssl/tls not working at localhost in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, ssl, express

https module not working at my localhost. I have go through this [blog.mgechev.com](http://blog.mgechev.com/2014/02/19/create-https-tls-ssl-application-with-express-nodejs/) tutorial. My node v5.10.1.

Here code:

```
//index.js
var fs = require('fs'),
https = require('https'),
express = require('express'),
app = express();

https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
}, app).listen(55555);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.header('Content-type', 'text/html');
  return res.end('<h1>Hello, Secure World!</h1>');
});
```

> node index.js

Output:

[image]

Comment: Try https://localhost:55555

Comment: i try this but it automatically redirected to `www.localhost.com:55555`

Comment: Are you writing the password on terminal after node server starts?

Comment: i have remove password according to `blog.mgechev.com` tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is silly mistake. I just hit url with preceding `https` and it working fine.

***That is:-***

> **https:**//localhost:55555